# Why can't I offer a bounty for my question?

Tags: support, bounty

Hey everyone,

Just wondering why I'm not able to offer a bounty here?

[Creating a file server - How can I use a large VHD file in Hyper-V? (700GB)](https://serverfault.com/questions/66513/creating-a-file-server-how-can-i-use-a-large-vhd-file-in-hyper-v-700gb)

It's been well past 2 days and I have some reputation left I'm willing to slice off.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

You [need at least 100](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5338/please-dont-suggest-starting-a-bounty-to-users-who-are-unable-to-do-so) rep before you can slice off your ear and offer it up to someone as part of a bounty.